# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in windows for php7

Tags: php, mysqli

I am consistently getting the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
> if I try to connect mysql with php.

I am a beginner to php and I have tried almost every solution suggested on Stack Overflow but to no avail. Some said to remove semicolons before selected statements from php.ini file. In php7, there were two files but none of them was php.ini. One was development and one was production. Both similar.

I deleted the development one and renamed the production file to php.ini as various answers suggested. Then I removed semicolons from the beginning of:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

and

```
extension = mysqli
```

I did pretty much everything different answers suggested. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try finding your extensions directory (e.g. `C:\php7\ext`) and then adding that path into the `extension_dir` value.

Comment: Try also running `php -i` to see if there are any mysqli extension start-up errors.

Comment: Also make sure you're editing the right php.ini file. If you're running PHP through a webserver such as apache or nginx, you can add `phpinfo();` on top of your script and you'll find the location of the right php.ini file. If you're using it through cli, `php -i` will give you the right path instead.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the response. I tried adding the path to the extension directory into the extension_dir value, but to no avail. Also, php -i returned a lot of information and frankly speaking, I really can't figure out much of it.

Comment: @Jeto Thanks to you too for responding. It seems I got what you want to tell as when I ran the php -i command, one of the statements read: " Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\windows
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none) " I guess this is what I was meant to try. But I really can't make out what I should do next. Sorry if it's all obvious, but I am really struggling as a beginner

Comment: Can you do a `php -i > phpinfo.txt` on the command line, paste the contents of that file in a GitHub Gist or pasteboard, and send me the link here?

Comment: Alternatively have a look at the top of the file, specifically at these fields: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php7
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php7/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php7/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)`. They will show you what files are actually being parsed - remember you could be editing the wrong file.

Comment: @halfer Yes, I have these here:                                                                                               " Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\windows Loaded Configuration File => (none) Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none) Additional .ini files parsed => (none) " Does that mean there is a php.ini file in C:\windows which I need to edit ?                                           Also note that "php -i > phpinfo.txt" doesn't return any output

Comment: Yes, `php -i > phpinfo.txt` does not produce console output - it redirects all the output to the specified file. That's the purpose of the `>` device.

Comment: I would guess, based on your output, that your ini file needs to be in `C:\windows\php.ini`. Try adding your file in there, including your `mysqli` config, and then try `php -i` again to see if this includes a `mysqli` section.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any file named php.ini in C:\windows.                                                Here is the gist link phpinfo.txt file as you asked for: [link](https://gist.github.com/Prasann00/64b381db5eaaf52b79c6d8ef583455d8)

Comment: OK, so try moving the `php.ini` file (from wherever it is now) into `C:\windows`. Then try `php -i` again, see if you get a `mysqli` section (your Gist does not have one at the mo).

Comment: I did that, but still mysqli section is not shown in php -i . Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/Prasann00/bc0d31d8085109a273d253e8ef5047fc) to the contents of my php.ini file. I am really confused as to which statements should not have a semicolon at the beginning and which should. It would be really helpful @halfer if you could edit the file as required or tell me whatever I need to do. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that all strings in INI files need to be quoted. So try using `extension_dir = "C:\Users\Prassanna Nand Jha\Desktop\PHP\ext"` instead.

Comment: However, I would also consider moving the `PHP` folder to `C:\PHP`, your desktop is not a good permanent place for it. **Don't do this though until you have tried the quotes change**. One thing at a time.

Comment: Also, try `php -v` and ensure there are no errors. Sometimes extensions fail to load, and any errors output will explain why.

Comment: You have also enabled `extension=mysqli` twice. That probably won't be the problem, but remove one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this can be a bit tricky, especially on Windows. Here are a few things to try, based on the comments conversation.

The first thing to do is to ensure your `php.ini` is in the right place. Do a `php -i` and note the values of these fields:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php7
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php7/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php7/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

Those values are for Linux, but the same principle applies - the first line indicates to me that it will look in `/etc/php7/php.ini` by default, and the second line indicates that it found the same. We found in the comments that your equivalent is `C:\windows` (and `C:\windows\php.ini`).

The second thing to do is to enable the mysqli module using `extension=mysqli`. You appear to have done that OK.

The next thing is to point the `extension_dir` at the correct place. By default I think this is `.`, which means the same folder as your PHP folder (`C:\Users\Prassanna Nand Jha\Desktop\PHP`). Try `"ext"` or `"./ext"` or `"C:\Users\Prassanna Nand Jha\Desktop\PHP\ext"` or `"C:/Users/Prassanna Nand Jha/Desktop/PHP/ext"` here. I am not sure if quotes are required, but I would generally go with, rather than without.

For each change you make, do `php -i` to see if the change was successful. Redirect this into a file if the Windows command environment makes the contents fly by without being able to read all of it.

If that does not work, consider moving `C:\Users\Prassanna Nand Jha\Desktop\PHP` to `C:\PHP` - maybe the spaces are upsetting it.

Finally if that still does not work, I wonder if you should just move this PHP installation to your wastebin and install XAMPP - that's an all-in-one installer that should work out of the box.